# Is there any situation where one can measure force WITHOUT motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, measurements, statics, displacement

I am drafting a patent application where one part of the invention measures a force.  I'd like to distinguish this from the prior art, which measures a displacement.  But for all the force measurement methods I know about, there's some kind of motion or deformation or reconfiguration going on.  (For example, a piezo sensor produces a signal proportional to force, but there is deformation going on in the crystal.)

Is there any way to measure change in force *without* motion or deformation?  (Perhaps I can distinguish the displacement sensors as "displacement *without* force" -- after all, two things can be in different places, without some particular force required to keep them apart.)

Comment: Are you asking for situations in which there is no *actual* motion/deformation, or no *potential* motion/deformation. In the former case there is the beam balance or current balance. The potential is there, but the measurement is made when there is no motion/deformation.

Comment: If you draft a patent application for your invention, and you know that it works, then I don't think you have to ask us. Anyways, I believe it's off topic here.

Comment: I don't understand...if you're measuring a system in balance where one side is known and the other side is inferred to be equal, I guess there's no motion, but you're also not measuring a change in force.  So perhaps that's what I need to ask: is there a way to measure a change in force without an accompanying motion or deformation?

Comment: Invention works, but patent application must describe it accurately.  I would like to say "measuring force *instead of* measuring displacement," but if all methods of measuring force are accompanied by a change in displacement, then my statement is inaccurate (and may be describing something that's impossible.)

Comment: With a beam balance, if the force to be measured changes then you increase the moment arm on the other side to compentate, to find when the displacement is again zero. ... It seems to me that what you are trying to do is find a suitable wording which will not invalidate your patent application.  Your question might be better in Ask Patents SE.

Comment: force is a vector and is defined as dp/dt, where p is momentum. Momentum means velocity times mass an velocity, the basis vector is ds/dt, a vector change in space.

Comment: I didn't know about Patents SE...will check over there, thanks.  It sounds like **F=mA**, and **A** correlates to position, so you can't get away from some kind of motion.  (*Increase* the moment arm -- you only know to do that if the system is out of balance, and you only know that it's out of balance if it moves!)

Comment: MEMS accelerometers (such as air bag sensors) work by detecting very small displacements capacitively and applying a counter force to keep the sensor motionless. The acceleration is then derived from the voltage needed to keep the sensor part steady. So, yes, very small movement is needed, but it is rapidly corrected for.

Comment: Right, those "very small movements" were what I was thinking about, and why I was wondering if there was a movement-less measurement method.  (I was thinking specifically of changes in electrical resistance due to stress, but I think *any* kind of stress in a real material produces a corresponding strain, even though the modulus might be astronomical.)

Comment: There are no "perfectly rigid" materials in real life. Any form of force will create a stress and therefore produce *some* motion. In practice of course the motion may be so small that you can ignore it - but there are many well known force transducers devices that already use that fact, so you probably need something more specific to claim a patent on a new device.

Comment: The question does seem a bit odd.  If your invention indeed measures force without displacement, then there is a method of measuring force without displacement and you didn't need to ask the question.  If your invention measures force via. displacement, then your description for the patent is incorrect regardless of the question.

Comment: @alephzero Basically what I was going to say.  I can't think of any way to apply this beyond an infinitely rigid bar, which is non-physical.

Comment: If anybody wants to submit the answer "No," I'll accept it.  It covers what I needed to know.  For patent purposes, I'll need to focus on another aspect in the description.  There's certainly a difference between "measuring force *here*" and "measuring displacement *there*," but it's not that "there's no displacement when you measure the force."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deformation** (by which I mean changes in relative positions or velocities of a system's constituents) is part of the very *meaning* of the force concept. Indeed, when acceleration occurs without any accompanying deformation, we are inclined to assume that the acceleration is a manifestation of the choice of a non-inertial reference frame rather than a force. That is precisely the reasoning behind the modern view that gravity should not be thought of as a force.

So it all depends on whether you are trying to eliminate distortion **for all practical purposes**, or trying to do so as **a matter of principle**. I would argue that the latter is impossible, but the former is perfectly doable.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between measuring a force versus a displacement is the difference between measuring an acceleration versus a position.

To measure acceleration, you need position as a function of time. If your displacement measurement is too slow, it cannot give an accurate force measurement.